# ionic 2 / rxjs5 / cordova network plugin event observable

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2, rxjs5

is it somehow possible to make an rxjs observable with the [fromEvent method](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromEvent) out of the [cordova network connection plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information).

i am trying that with ionic 2.

i can see, that there are two events (online/offline) in the [cordova network connection plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information). but how to hook into them with rxjs?

something that looks like that:

```
const offline$ = Observable.fromEvent(CORDOVA_OFFLINE_EVENT);
offline$.subscribe(
    function (connectionType) {
        console.log("connectionType", JSON.stringify(connectionType));
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it normally like the documentation says (`document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);`), and in the handler you can emit with an EventEmitter or if you still want to use observable you can dispatch custom event to the document and make `Observable.fromEvent(document, 'nameofevent')`

Example:

```
window.addEventListener('offline', this.onOffline);
onOffline(e) {
        var event = new CustomEvent('onoffline');
        event['offlineTimestamp'] = new Date()
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
```

and than just `this.networkObservable = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'onoffline');`

or instead of dispatching CustomEvent, you can have an EventEmitter which will emit in the handlers

```
networkEmitter = new EventEmitter();
window.addEventListener('offline', onOffline);
    onOffline(e) {
            this.networkEmitter.emit('wentOffline');
        }
```

You can than subscribe in the EventEmitter or Observable :)